# jq - Looping through json and concatenate the output to single string

Tags: json, bash, sh, jq

I was currently learning the usage of `jq`. I have a json file and I am able to loop through and filter out the values I need from the json. However, I am running into issue when I try to combine the output into single string instead of having the output in multiple lines.

File `svcs.json`:

```
[ 
 {
   "name": "svc-A",
   "run" : "True"
 },
 {
   "name": "svc-B",
   "run" : "False"
 },
 {
   "name": "svc-C",
   "run" : "True"
 }
]
```

I was using the jq to filter to output the service names with `run` value as `True`

`jq -r '.[] | select(.run=="True") | .name ' svcs.json`

I was getting the output as follows:

```
 svc-A
 svc-C
```

I was looking to get the output as single string separated by commas.

Expected Output:

`"svc-A,svc-C"`

I tried to using join, but was unable to get it to work so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.[]` expression explodes the array into a stream of its elements. You'll need to collect the transformed stream (the names) back into an array. Then you can use the `@csv` filter for the final output

```bash
$ jq -r '[ .[] | select(.run=="True") | .name ] | @csv' svcs.json
"svc-A","svc-C"
```

But here's where `map` comes in handy to operate on an array's elements:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map(select(.run=="True") | .name) | @csv' svcs.json
"svc-A","svc-C"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked as per question. Just curious, is there a way to output the same as list of string ?  Something like [“svc-A”, “svc-C”] ?

Comment: Just remove `|@csv`

Answer (score 2):

Keep the array using `map` instead of decomposing it with `.[]`, then join with a glue string:

```bash
jq -r 'map(select(.run=="True") | .name) | join(",")' svcs.json
```

```json
svc-A,svc-C
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0Jq3akjPEqB)

---

If your goal is to create a CSV output, there is a special `@csv` command taking care of quoting, escaping etc.

```bash
jq -r 'map(select(.run=="True") | .name) | @csv' svcs.json
```

```json
"svc-A","svc-C"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GcZn4SSnWXb)